# Oauth Password Grant and client website

Tags: php, angularjs, authentication, laravel, oauth

I am using these excellent tools, Laravel 5, thephpleague/oauth2-server, lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel and AngularJS.

I have both an api and authorization server with domain api.dev.

I have a client website with domain client.dev.

The client website have areas for admin and members.

I am using the OAuth 2 Resource Owner Password grant type to access the api.

Right now, I have a login form on the client website admin area. The user inputs his/her username and password and submits the form. The client website then makes a post curl request to the auth server using the password grant, appending the username and password to the client id and secret, etc. Then it handles the response from the auth server and redirects accordingly if it was a success (admin dashboard) or not (login form with error message).

This works fine.

My question is, right now, the client website does not know who the user is (admin or member) up until the user has obtained an access token. When it makes a request to the api for a resource, only then I can use methods like Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId() to check who the user is.

Here is a scenario as described above. A member may login to the admin area, gets an access token and be redirected to the dashboard. Then an angular $http.get fires to get a resource (filtered by oauth) to be displayed on the dashboard. The client website checks and finds out that the user is actually not an admin (by the Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId()) and thus logs out and redirect the user back to the login form.

The user should not have been able to logged in successfully in the first place.

Is my setup wrong? Or if it is not, how do I deal with this properly?

Should I have an identical users table both on the client and api/auth server so that I could check immediately if the user logging in on the client is admin or not.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Why dont you add one more column in your table ie. is_admin and set it to boolean.And when you are trying to login check if is admin is set ot not.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up extending these two classes and methods:

League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant::completeFlow() - I have included the user_id to be set and be passed to the Bearer class below.

League\OAuth2\Server\TokenType\Bearer::generateResponse() - Checks if the user_id exists and include it to be passed on the response.

Of course the sub-classes were now used on the config of lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel in lieu of their parent classes.

Essentially, the password grant returns this data now:

```
array (
  'access_token' => 'P9d4ChYm4UGMMqMuuhI250inNiD3NKlIM7cFuVB2',
  'token_type' => 'Bearer',
  'expires_in' => 10,
  'refresh_token' => 'G6WgBEWKakl9vc6jJesFGDUc1wlja8SwuOV7kg8y',
  'user_id' => 2,
)
```

Comment: Just make sure your client cannot change the user_id or they will be able to promote themselves.  I'm assuming you are using a signed token (json web token perhaps) to send the grant.

Comment: I'm using the oauth 2 password grant via a proxy as recommended by Alex Bilbie. Here's the link: http://alexbilbie.com/2014/11/oauth-and-javascript/

Comment: As long as your grant payload is signed somehow (i.e. encypted cookie) then great.  I myself would use an authorization header instead of cookies but that's just me.  The only other thing you might consider is adding scopes (i.e. roles or permission groups) to you payload.  roles='ROLE_ADMIN'.  That would allow your authentication process to check some things without needing to access the actual user.  It's also something that can be used client side to help restrict the available routes.

Comment: Yes. I'm using also scopes and the cookies are encrypted. The user_id just basically lets me know sooner rather than later if I should let the user continue on the dashboard or not. The client won't have to wait for a response on a request to a resource filtered by oauth only to find out that the user is not an admin and thus logs out and redirects the user back to the login form. Thank you for taking the time to comment on this @Cerad